# Stop gmail + terminal from pasting rich text

Tags: terminal, google-chrome, gmail

Since some recent update, when copying stuff from Terminal into Gmail compose window, it's pasted as formatted text, retaining all my terminal colors and fonts.

[image]

How to stop them (Chrome, Gmail, Terminal or whoever is to blame) doing that? This is really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change Gmail composition to plain text or use Paste and Match Style.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the trick was to disable that in Terminal prefs.